# Method overload and type conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, overloading

I have two C# conversion methods:

```
public int MyConvertToInteger(double x) {
  if (x > int.MaxValue) {
    return int.MaxValue;
  } else if (x < int.MinValue || double.IsNaN(x)) {
    return int.MinValue;
  } else {
    return (int)x;
  }
}

public int MyConvertToInteger(string str) {
  if (str == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return str.Length;
}
```

and one business method, with two possible types for each argument, resulting in four overloads:

```
public int IntSum(int x, int y) { 
  unchecked {
    return x+y; 
  }
}

public int IntSum(int x, string y) { 
  int iy = MyConvertToInteger(y);
  return IntSum(x, iy);
}

public int IntSum(double x, int y) {
  int ix = MyConvertToInteger(x);
  return IntSum(ix, y);
}

public int IntSum(double x, string y) {
  int ix = MyConvertToInteger(x);
  return IntSum(ix, y);
}
```

That is annoying but practical. However, If I were to add a third argument with two possible types, we would be up to eight overloads, which IMO is beyond the pale.

I am wondering if there is a way to somehow specify the possible conversions in the method argument, so that we don't get this profusion of overloads? (I am not interested in "solutions" which involve taking arguments of a more general type such as "object", then inspecting the type of whatever is passed in.)

Comment: Why not ```int sum(params int[] args)``` and ```sum(FromDouble(d), FromString(s), FromAnything(anything))``` ?

Comment: fixed, thanks. @tym32167 -- just assume I don't want to do that.

Comment: Can I ask where it makes sense to do what you're doing? I can't see where you could possibly have a need to convert a string to int where that means the strings length and not a number string - and then do calculations on this. It sounds to me like the problem is else where and this is just complicating things..

Comment: It's a toy example, just using length to keep things simple while illustrating the general issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

> I am wondering if there is a way to somehow specify the possible
>   conversions in the method argument, so that we don't get this
>   profusion of overloads?

No. It's not possible in C#.

Sometimes it's essential to create many overloads especially when  performance is at stake. I've seen projects with something like 50 overloads created for one method. What is possible however is to run more strict overloads from more generic ones, in other words `Sum(x ,y, z)` overload can run two `(x, y)` + `(y, z)` so there no real need to write any other logic inside of more generic overloads just to re-use one that already exist.

The only other option is to accept `params object[]` and determine what types we work with, create composite types, or use`dynamic`'s .

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice, but take a look on that

```
void Main()
{
    var result = new Summer().Sum("1", 2, 3.0);
}

public class Summer
{
    private int Convert<T>(T source)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private int Convert(int source)
    {
        return source;
    }

    private int Convert(string source)
    {
        return source.Length;
    }

    private int Convert(double source)
    {
        return (int)source;
    }


    public int Sum<T, K>(T i1, K i2)
    {
        return Convert((dynamic)i1) + Convert((dynamic)i2);
    }

    public int Sum<T, K, S>(T i1, K i2, S i3)
    {
        return Convert((dynamic)i1) + Convert((dynamic)i2)+ Convert((dynamic)i3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. As you say, it's bad practice. I think this means the answer to my original question is "no." Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom composite type, for example int or double could be expressed as

```
    public class IntOrDouble
    {
        int i;
        double d;
        public enum MyType
        {
            None,
            Int,
            Double
        }
        MyType myType;
        public IntOrDouble(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
            myType = MyType.Int;
        }
        public IntOrDouble(double d)
        {
            this.d = d;
            myType = MyType.Double;
        }
        public MyType GetReturnType()
        {
            return myType;
        }
        public int GetInt()
        {
            if (!myType.Equals(MyType.Int))
            {
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            }
            return i;
        }
        public double GetDouble()
        {
            if (!myType.Equals(MyType.Double))
            {
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            }
            return d;
        }
}
```

but that'd imply you have to rewrite your method as

```
    public int IntSum(IntOrDouble x, IntOrString y)
```

**Edit** The generic version (in case of repeated usage)

```
    public enum MyType
    {
        None,
        T1,
        T2
    }
    public class CompositeType<T1,T2>
    {
        T1 i;
        T2 d;
        MyType myType;
        public CompositeType(T1 i)
        {
            this.i = i;
            myType = MyType.T1;
        }
        public CompositeType(T2 d)
        {
            this.d = d;
            myType = MyType.T2;
        }
        public MyType GetReturnType()
        {
            return myType;
        }
        public T1 GetT1()
        {
            if (!myType.Equals(MyType.T1))
            {
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            }
            return i;
        }
        public T2 GetT2()
        {
            if (!myType.Equals(MyType.T2))
            {
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            }
            return d;
        }
        public object GetValue()
        {
            switch (myType)
            {
                case MyType.None:
                    throw new Exception("wrong type");
                case MyType.T1:
                    return GetT1();
                case MyType.T2:
                    return GetT2();
                default:
                    throw new Exception("wrong type");
            }

        }
    }
```

Usage

```
    public int CompositeConversion<T>(CompositeType<int, T> x)
    {
        switch (x.GetReturnType())
        {
            case MyType.None:
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            case MyType.T1:
                return x.GetT1();
            case MyType.T2:
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
                {
                    return MyConvertToInteger((double)x.GetValue());
                }
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                {
                    return MyConvertToInteger((string)x.GetValue());
                }
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
            default:
                throw new Exception("wrong type");
        }
    }
    public int IntSum(CompositeType<int,double> x, CompositeType<int, string> y)
    {
        return CompositeConversion(x) + CompositeConversion(y);
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
        int test1 = t.IntSum(3.7, "55.9");
        int test2 = t.IntSum(
            new CompositeType<int,double>(3.7), 
            new CompositeType<int,string>("55.9")
            ); // test1 and test2 are both 7
```

Comment: It looks like overcomplicated variation of ```sum(FromDouble(d), FromString(s), FromAnything(anything))```

Comment: @tym32167 No, it is different, the above is not suggesting the possible types of the argument and it is not forcing only one conversion from a type  to another